# Any Issues if I use toLong instead of new Long() to convert string Long

Tags: java

Can any one tell me the difference between `toLong()` and `new Long(String)`? Are there any differences in performance between the two?

Example : `String str="1236";`

`Long val=str.toLong();`

OR

`Long val=new Long(str);`

Which one is better usage and give me the differences?

Comment: In which version of Java do you see `String.toLong()`?

Comment: If String.toLong() existed, its javadoc would tell you what it does. But this method doesn't exist. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: You mean Long.parseLong(String), right?

Answer (score 2):

(I assume you mean in Groovy, since Java Strings don't have a `toLong()` method...)

Under the covers, the same code is use so there is no difference.

If you are still curious, however, I would *strongly* suggest writing a quick timing test to verify for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long.valueOf(...)` as it caches and re-uses values below 128 (i guess).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `String#toLong()` method.

But there is `Long#valueOf(String)` which should be used instead of `new Long(String)` since the JVM can cache and reuse the value.

Comment: Just checked and it seems that the version that takes a String-argument is not using cached values...

Comment: Oh yes... I just had a look at the javadoc, and it lets me suspect that you're right... Seems the same for `Integer` (didn't check the others). Well, learned something new today. Thx for the hint! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no String.toLong() - but there is Long.valueOf(String str) which is doing the same as new Long(String str).